# firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update an array in my firestore, 
i followed the documentation provided by Google (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) but It doesn't work, I also checked to make sure I have the latest version of the firebase npm module.

Here's my code:

```
> db
                    .collection('Data')
                    .doc('One')
                    .collection('Doc')
                    .doc(this.$route.params.id.toLowerCase())
                    .update({
                        myArr: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                           'test'
                        ),
                    })
                    .then(() => console.log('Successfully written'))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Are you using NodeJS, or vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I'm doing this on the front end of my Vuejs app, so It's not a node JS runtime.

Comment: This feature was introduced in version 5.3.0 of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript. Are you using that version or later?

Comment: Thanks, I double checked and yarn wasn't properly updating the module. I removed and reinstalled, fixed now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase npm module was out of date. Had to manually reinstall

Comment: had the same issue until I upgraded to 5.5.9 (from 5.1.0) \n [though a commenter above says 5.3.0 added it]

Answer (score 4):

From this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/323)

> This has been released as part of @google-cloud/firestore v0.16.0. It is not yet available via Firebase Admin, but will be released shortly. Note that the function name is `admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()`.

Answer (score 3):

If your using the new modular version 9 for javascript use the code below

```
import { getFirestore, arrayUnion, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
const db = getFirestore(config);    
const pathRef = doc(db, "doc", "id");
    await updateDoc(pathRef , {
        myArr: arrayUnion("test")
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const arrayToUpdate = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(value)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer at this date, using V8.

Answer (score 1):

"firebase-admin": "^6.0.0", is the version where `arrayUnion` was added.
Upgrade the npm package.

Check https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/CHANGELOG.md#060

Comment: I believe 5.5.9 has it too (as does 5.3.0  according to a commenter above)

Comment: @user3294126 no. It was on version 6.0.0. Check it: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/CHANGELOG.md#060

Comment: I verified it manually, your link doesn't include all releases